# Hat trick for bowler including a run out

Tags: cricket

Usually, if a bowler takes two wickets in three balls and the third is a run-out, this is not a hat trick since the bowler is not credited with the wicket for the run-out.

However, if it's the bowler who got the run-out, is it a hat trick?

Edit: this literally just happened in the Southern Brave v Trent Rockets men's game in the Hundred, Chris Jordan got a run-out and then bowled two in two. He was not credited with a hat trick, instead the next ball was hat trick ball... but is he not credited with a wicket for the run-out?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because fundamentally the answer is the same: a hat-trick is whatever the newspapers of the day decide it is, it has no official definition nor bearing on the game.